# How to debug stored procedures in Sybase?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I work with Sybase Central 4.3.0.2428 and the server is Sybase ASE 16.0 SP01 PL03/EBF 24830.

I would like to debug stored procedures.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a command line tool called [sqldbgr](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SYBASE/sqldbgr). Look for the manual to check the parameters and commands.

Years ago Sybase has released a Eclipse based suite called [Sybase Workspace](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.pubs.docset-SWS-2.0.0/projects/common/infocenter/product_docset/c_SWS-200_docset_landing_page.html). It had included an interface for the SQL debugger. But the product is no longer maintained and is no longer available. You will have trouble to find the binaries.